# How do I make auto-complete enabled by default

Tags: init-file, auto-complete-mode

I'm running GNU Emacs 24.4.1 on a clean install of Debian 8.1.  I've installed auto-complete using the package manager.  It is installed and if I type `M-x auto-complete-mode` I get a working auto-complete.  I would like to have it enabled by default.  I added the following to my .emacs file:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

However, that resulted in the error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/greg/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, auto-complete
```

So, I tried adding to the load path with a bunch of different attempts like:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path' ("~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
```

OR

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (file-name-as-directory
                     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20151211.227/auto-complete"))
                     )
```

But nothing seems to do the trick.  If I use `C-h v load-path` when I run emacs with `--debug-init`, I can see what I've added to the load path, but even when it looks correctly I still get the same can't load file error.

I've read other similar questions but these are all the things their answers said to try and I still can't get it to work.  How do I get auto-complete to load automatically?

Comment: I guess it's just a typo: `(require'autocomplete)`.

Comment: @Nsukami_  The typo was somehow made copying things over for the question.  I sometime type emacs commands into the edit box out of habit...The .emacs file has the correct hyphenation.

Comment: I have never had this issue, so I was looking at my config to see what I had that you didn't, and the only thing is `(require 'auto-complete-config)`. You can try adding that to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @elethan It still doesn't seem to be finding auto-complete.  I think it is a problem with the load-path but I'm not sure it is and I just can't seem to nail it down.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @GregoryArenius, you also have a  few typos in the line `(add-to-list 'load-path' ("~/.emacs.d/elpa/")` this should be `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to create a minimal config that would have a working `auto-complete` and this is what I came up with.

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)  ;load and activate packages, including auto-complete

(ac-config-default)

(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

Try that out and see if it works.

Additionally, you can use:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'name-of-mode)
```

If `auto-complete` doesn't work by default with a given mode. E.g., `(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'sql-mode)`. Also, see [the manual](http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html) for more details on configuration, etc.

Comment: This doesn't return any error messages but it also doesn't seem to make it so that auto-complete is auto-enabled.  When this is in my .emacs and I open a file and type `M-x auto-complete` it tells me that auto-complete is not enabled.  Which is strange because `(global-auto-complete-mode t)` should do that...

Comment: Alright.  So I played around with it some more.  This will auto-load auto-complete for some files and not others.  For instance if I open a new file test.py it open in Python AC mode with working auto-complete.  If I open test.sql however I don't get any auto-complete.  I think it has to do with what modes are in the dict directory where auto-complete is installed.  If I have test.sql open however and manually start auto-complete it does work.

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit, but as far as I know, without further configuration, `global-auto-complete-mode` will only offer completions for text that already in the buffer. If you won't better completions and completions specific to certain languages, you will have to configure things a bit more. Also, you might check out `company-mode`http://company-mode.github.io/ I have had better luck with that for auto-completion personally.

Comment: What does the (ac-config-default) line do?

Comment: `(ac-config-default)` sets up some default auto-complete sources, and adds hooks to a few major modes. To see exactly what it does you can use `C-h f` to get help with a function, enter `ac-config-default`, and then, where it says "ac-config-default is an autoloaded Lisp function in \`auto-complete-config.el'." click/hit return on the file name `auto-complete-config.el` and it should take you directly to the source where the function is defined. This is a generally useful way to look up function info.