# auto complete isn't loaded || elpa OSX

Tags: osx, auto-complete-mode, popup

emacs version 26.3 OSX 10.14.1 
Following is my .init file. It is present at `~/.emacs.d`

```lisp
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/") ;; on may 01 2020
(require 'popup) ;; dependancy 
(require 'auto-complete)

(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.saves"))) ;; this work totally fine
```

In my home directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa` is present

How do I enable that auto-complete works?

I don't know if the path for elpa is being read although I've added it to the list.

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18982/how-do-i-make-auto-complete-enabled-by-default

Comment: thank you. It doesn't help. It isn't enabled, let alone global or, mode specific issue. :).

Comment: Looks like you need to add, at least, `(ac-config-default)`. Probably you have it enabled but you don't have any sources to provide completion.

Comment: @Muihlinn `ac-config-default` isn't helping.

Comment: You need to turn on (global-auto-complete-mode 1) or its equivalent. Another option is to add a specific auto-complete setup function to the init hook of the mode you are interested in using it with. More info is available in its docs.